# Back-transforming elasticities to level coefficients, with standard errors

Tags: regression, back-transformation

I would like to use some literature estimates of supply and demand price elasticities in an illustrative model that is in levels, not logs.

The elasticities come from models of the kind
$$
\ln Y=\beta \ln X + \varepsilon
$$

So $\beta$ can be roughly interpreted as a percentage change in Y from a percentage change in X.

I need to use these Betas in a model that is in levels. If I know reference values (means) for both $X$ and $Y$, how can I back-transform the Betas to levels?
The literature estimates also report standard errors--how can I back-transform these to levels as well?

Edit: I've realized the Betas are relatively easy to back-transform. Since
$$
\beta\approx {\% \Delta Y \over \% \Delta X} = {\Delta Y / \bar Y \over \Delta X / \bar X}={\Delta Y \over \Delta X} \frac{\bar X}{\bar Y}
$$
Multiplying $\beta$ by the ratio of the means $\frac{\bar Y}{\bar X}$ yields $\frac{\Delta Y}{\Delta X}$, which is what I'm after. However, the back-transformation of the standard errors still remains...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the elasticity formula $$\epsilon = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{x}{y}.$$

You know $\epsilon$ and you can use the means, $\bar y$ and $ \bar x$.

To get $$\mathbb{Var} \left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \right)=\mathbb{Var} \left( \epsilon \cdot \frac{\bar y}{\bar x} \right)=\mathbb{Var} \left( \epsilon \right) \cdot \left( \frac{\bar y}{\bar x} \right)^2,$$ and you know $\mathbb{Var}(\epsilon)$ from the regression. This variance is likely be too narrow compared to the one you might actually estimate from a regression of $Y$ on $X$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To clarify, did you mean $\epsilon = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{y}{x}$? Or did you intend $\epsilon = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{x}{y}$? I thought the fraction of y and x was flipped, from what I wrote above...

Comment: Indeed. Typo fixed!